# Confused by basic callback function

Tags: javascript, callback

I need help with a basic callback function.  I have a main index.html file that references script.js.  Inside of index.html, it simply calls app.initialize(); to initialize the function from script.js.  Here's the code for script.js below:

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    tokenHandler:function(msg) {
        console.log("Token Handler " + msg);
        alert(msg);
    },
    errorHandler:function(error) {
        console.log("Error Handler  " + error);
        alert(error);
    },
    // result contains any message sent from the plugin call
    successHandler: function(result) {
        alert('Success! Result = '+result)
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        // TODO: Enter your own GCM Sender ID in the register call for Android
        if (device.platform == 'android' || device.platform == 'Android') {
            pushNotification.register(this.successHandler, this.errorHandler,{"senderID":"SENDER ID HERE","ecb":"app.onNotificationGCM"});
        }
        else {
            pushNotification.register(this.tokenHandler,this.errorHandler,{"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"app.onNotificationAPN"});
        }
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    },
    // iOS
    onNotificationAPN: function(event) {
        var pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;
        console.log("Received a notification! " + event.alert);
        console.log("event sound " + event.sound);
        console.log("event badge " + event.badge);
        console.log("event " + event);
        if (event.alert) {
            navigator.notification.alert(event.alert);
        }
        if (event.badge) {
            console.log("Set badge on  " + pushNotification);
            pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(this.successHandler, event.badge);
        }
        if (event.sound) {
            var snd = new Media(event.sound);
            snd.play();
        }
    },
    // Android
    onNotificationGCM: function(e) {
        switch( e.event )
        {
            case 'registered':
                if ( e.regid.length > 0 )
                {
                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    alert('registration id = '+e.regid);

                    // Your GCM push server needs to know the regID before it can push to this device
                    // here is where you might want to send it the regID for later use.
                    PushWoosh.appCode = "CODE GOES HERE";
                    PushWoosh.register(e.regid, function(data) {
                         alert("PushWoosh register success: " + JSON.stringify(data));
                     }, function(errorregistration) {
                         alert("Couldn't register with PushWoosh" +  errorregistration);
                     });
                }
            break;

            case 'message':
                // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
                if ( e.foreground )
                {
                    alert(e.payload.message);
                    alert(e.payload.pagenotification);

                }
                else
                {  // otherwise we were launched because the user touched a notification in the notification tray.
                    if ( e.coldstart )
                    {
                        alert(e.payload.message);
                        alert(e.payload.pagenotification);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(e.payload.message);
                        alert(e.payload.pagenotification);
                    }
                }
            break;

            case 'error':
              alert('GCM error = '+e.msg);
            break;

            default:
              alert('An unknown GCM event has occurred');
              break;
        }
    }
};
```

Inside of onNotificationGCM, on the "message" case at either the foreground/coldstart situations, I'd like to return e.payload.pagenotification back to the main index.html page where app.initialize() was called.  Is there any way someone can explain how I can go about return this information to the index page.

any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!
-- 24x7

Answer (score 0):

Have a global variable in your index.html and update this variable from the foreground / coldstart code block, that way you will have the variable contain the information which you can use in index.html

Answer (score 0):

So events basically are lists of listeners (callbacks) that will be called when the event is emitted.

You can create your own app events.
With that you can listen to those app events, from your `index page`.

I will try to help based on what I understood of your problem, using a different example.

**Source of index.html**

```
<html>
 <script type='text/html' src='script.js'></script>
 <script type='text/html'>
    app.event.addEventListener('notificationGCM', function (e) {
       // you can access the event data
       console.log(e.detail.x);
    });
    app.emit('notificationGCM',{ x: 1 });
 </script>
</html>
```

**Source of script.js**

```
function myApp() {
    this.initialize();
}

myApp.prototype = {

    initialize: function () {
        this.event = document.createElement('div');
        // do your stuff here
    },

    emit: function (eventName,data) {
        var event = new CustomEvent(eventName, { detail: data });
        this.event.dispatchEvent(event)
    },

    onNotificationGCM: function (e) {
        // do your stuff here
        this.events.notificationGCM.emit('notificationGCM',e);
    }

};

var app = new myApp;
```

On the example above, I created a `notificationGCM` event, but you can create any event that you want, emit them as you like and listen to them from the `index page`.